# Enterprise Architect: Data model to Class Model

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I've been modeling the Data entities from my project with EA, so far I've modelled all Tables from my database with their respective attributes, and now I would like to make a transformation to a Class diagram.

But I fear I've been doing the modeling wrong and somehow EA is not identifying my model as a Data Relational Model. See this screencap where it says "Class Diagram" although I am clearly talking about Tables here, with columns and foreign keys and such:

[image]

I tried right clicking on my package and selecting Transform Diagram but the resulting diagram looks very much like this one but with getters. Isn't there any way to automatically generate the classes with relationships mapped with collections and objects?

The idea is that I can generate the code after I'm done modeling and so far this transformation is not much of an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram type doesn't matter for transformations, but you can change it in the Diagram menu under Advanced. What you've drawn here, a set of database tables, should be in what EA calls a Data Modeling diagram.

Regarding transforming to a source code model, you won't get very far with EA's built-in transformations. You can transform your data(base) model to an Entity-Relationship Model or to a DBMS-specific model, but that's it. If you want to transform to an implementation-language model, you'll have to write your own transformation.

Comment: And how would I do that? (i.e. write my own transformation) Or do you mean creating a new diagram myself?